# Tracking how many times an HTML5 audio element is played?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, google-analytics

What is the best way to track how many times an HTML5 audio element is played?

(we can use Google Analytics too, if that is the best approach)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML5 Audio elements [have basic callbacks.](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox)

You can combine that with a basic event callback library like jQuery to attach these events by default:

```
$("audio").bind("play", function(){
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent","Audio", "play", $(this).attr('src')]);
});
```

You can also do similar events for tracking when people finish the audio:

```
$("audio").bind("ended", function(){
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent","Audio", "ended", $(this).attr('src')]);
});
```

This can be made more concise by combining them into a single call:

```
$("audio").bind("play ended", function(e){
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent","Audio", e.type, $(this).attr('src')]);
});
```

You can also add the events on the `<audio>` tag attributes as `onplay` and `onended`, but, I wouldn't recommend that approach.

Comment: @Yahel - I've added this code immediately after my analytics code in the head, but it doesn't seem to be tracking in Analytics. Where should the code be placed?

Comment: @Yahel - Yes, I've just wrapped in one, but it doesn't seem to be tracking still. How will this show in Analytics?

Comment: Tracked events should be separated by space, not comma:
$("audio").bind("play ended", ...

Comment: @SergeyStadnik thanks for flagging! Fixed. That's been wrong for 4 years!

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to Universal Analytics and are not using classic analytics, then you would use a send event not a push event: ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', e.type, $(this).attr('src'));
Also, if you were just testing this on your own, make sure you didn't create a filter to filter out your own IP address.