# How can I count the times an HTML5 video is played

Tags: html

I'm developing a site that shows videos from youtube, and I'm interested in knowing how many times each video has been played from my web. Youtube views doesn't count, just the views from my web. I've found this approach for audio:

[Tracking how many times an HTML5 audio element is played?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516068/tracking-how-many-times-an-html5-audio-element-is-played)

Can I use the same approach for videos? Someone has done this? How? I have found a similar question:

[Tracking the number of times a video was played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986979/tracking-the-number-of-times-a-video-was-played)

But the answer is not satisfying for me, I need to do it without a third party service, if it is possible, of course.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Media_events

Comment: It's a good resource, but only suitable for Firefox users, as far as I can see from theyr compatibility table. Is there another way? This would only be useful for firefox users, so I cannot rely on this approach.

Comment: I suspect that's unknown/untested for the others, rather than unsupported. e.g. safari: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/HTMLMediaElementClassReference/HTMLMediaElement/HTMLMediaElement.html

Comment: Internet Explorer 9: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772498.aspx

Comment: But there isn't a good resource which lists the browser support for the various events...

Comment: If you can sum your comments in an answer, I would like to select it as the correct answer, so you can earn reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

I adapted it to do what I wanted:

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.addEventListener("ended", function() { 
    alert('Video has been viewed!'); 
}, true);
```